# Tweak vscode SQL editing environment for postgres

Tags: postgresql, pgtyped

I'm getting started editing SQL in SQL files in a nextjs project in vscode. I want to work with pgtyped, so my SQL will have parameters, prefixed with a colon. I've installed Chris Kolkman's PostgreSQL extension for vscode, and the first thing to notice is that it doesn't like my parameters. Why is this? Can it be fixed or worked around?

[image]